# Ayuda para ajustar tamaño de una tabla

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla y no puedo cambiar su tamaño, tampoco a las celdas, solo me deja hacerlo hasta cierto punto.

Código de la tabla

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1"; width="520"> 

        <tr>
            <td width="100"  rowspan="4">
                
                    <img
                        width="100"
                        height="10"
                        src="img/44.png"/>
                  

            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                 <font size=1></font>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> CÓDIGO
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  colspan="3"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  FSW-100
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> <strong>DEPARTAMENTO DE LAS TIC</strong>
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  rowspan="2"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> VERSIÓN 1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  colspan="3" rowspan="2"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  01-12-17
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                 <font size=1>   Tecnologías de la información y las comunicaciones
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p  align="center" >
                 <font size=2>   <strong>Acta de Entrega</strong></font>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    PAGINA
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    DE
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  2
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Teniendo en cuenta el tamaño de la página quiero que quede así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te hace falta quitarle el `margin-bottom` a las `p` que tienen por default

Comment: como se quita el margin-bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez que le quites los `margin` a las `P` con eso podrás maniobrar la tabla:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ducument</title>
  
  <style>
   .logo{
    width: 200px;
   }
   p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1"; width="520">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="100"  rowspan="4">
      <img src="https://ii.ct-stc.com/1/logos/empresas/2017/06/05/comercializacion-y-distribucion-de-lubricantes-AD0A391FC17BF05B173537thumbnail.jpeg" alt="" class="logo">
     </td>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center"></p>
     </td>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center"><font size=1> CÓDIGO</p>
     </td>
     <td  colspan="3"  height="10">
      <p align="center"><font size=1>  FSW-100</p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1> <strong>DEPARTAMENTO DE LAS TIC</strong>
      <strong></strong>
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  rowspan="2"  height="10">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1> VERSIÓN 1
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  colspan="3" rowspan="2"  height="10">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>  01-12-17
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center">
       <font size=1>   Tecnologías de la información y las comunicaciones
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  height="18">
      <p  align="center" >
      <font size=2>   <strong>Acta de Entrega</strong></font>
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    PAGINA
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  height="10">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    1
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    DE
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  height="18">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>  2
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las etiquetas `p` tienen por default un `margin-bottom` y `margin-top`, esto hace que las celdas de la tabla se hagan mas grandes, por eso al ponerle 
`margin-top:0px`
`margin-bottom: 0px`
las celdas se ajustan al texto y se acomoda mejor.